# Centralize TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to centralize TabLayout when `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

My **TabLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorTabSelected"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTabNormal"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

With that layout. Tablayout like this (but all tabs are aligned left):

[image]

if `app:tabMode="fixed"`, the text in the center tab will have smaller size than the others.

[image]

So. I want make the same size of all text in TabLayout if `app:tabMode="fixed"` (all tabs are aligned central). If `app:tabMode="scrollable"`, I want to centralize tab(like tabMode `fixed`).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work around by adding padding, still in `app:tabMode="fixed"`

`app:tabMode="fixed"
app:tabPaddingEnd="1dp"
app:tabPaddingStart="1dp"`

to TabLayout.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartTabLayout](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1683) library could help you having your tabs always in center.

Comment: I used it before but I want something simpler like TabLayout. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Okay no problem.